# How to get My Twitter Home Timeline in Command Prompt Using PHP and Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, php

I want to get all my home timeline updates in my windows command line. I can provide the username and password in php code.

How is it possible to get a number of updates when I use following in my command prompt ?

```
php -f my_tweets.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's your [`home_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline), you need to be authenticated via twitter's website using [`PIN-based authorization`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization), twitter has stopped using the `username:password` thingy. This is very possible, you need to set up an app as a desktop client in twitter's developer page then work with [Oauth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries). See

Have you tried [Quitter](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=command%20line%20twitter%20quitter&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://www.twtbase.com/quitter/&ei=6D-2ToeDPYjQsgbuoPTSAw&usg=AFQjCNEoqWbXi7NP_Meo69oZZZxa9sXMCQ)? It's a command line twitter client. There are also [several others](http://www.google.com.ng/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=command%20line%20twitter).

Comment: thanks for the links. i will come back after the implementation.